# Can TDengine automatically delete a table when no data is written to for a certain time?

Tags: tdengine

As the title, I have a lot of time-series data with a lot of matrix creationg and deletion. Since some tables may become useless when there is no data to write for about one month. Is there a way to automatically delete a table when there is no more data to write for a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'create database dbname keep XXX' to set the time when the TDengine will delete the outdated data from your disk.